# Image is not shown until the row is clicked/tapped

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am working on ButtonRows with an image that is asynchronously downloaded, here's my code:

```
 futurSection <<< ButtonRow("aaa") {
            $0.title = ""
            }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
                cell.imageView?.imageFromServerURL("http://example.com/0x0ss2.jpg")
                row.reload()
            }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) -> () in
                row.cell.height = {
                    return 150
                }
            })
```

I used an extension for the UIImageView:

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String) {

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.image = image
                self.layoutSubviews()
                if let myViewController = self.parentViewController as? ShowDetails {
                    myViewController.form.rowByTag("aaa")?.updateCell()
                }

            })

        }).resume()
    }}
```

But the image in the row doesn't become visible until I click the row itself. I even called updateCell and reload but id doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: What do the raw.reload() ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a local image, did that work? May be the cells are loaded before they got the response from server. Are you updating cell after response received from server?

Comment: @bobby I was just trying if it would there.

Comment: @BhupeshPruthi Yes. The cells were loaded just before the images were loaded. I am trying to update the cell using the code the dispatch_async.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo copy `cell.imageView?.imageFromServerURL("http://example.com/0x0ss2.jpg")` to `cellSetup` seems  `eureka` won't trigger `cellUpdate ` when fist load.

Comment: @WilsonXJ same problem still

Comment: @JaysonTamayo  did local image show without click the row?

Comment: In below line, row.reload gets executed before you get the image. You need to make sure that row .reload is called after successful image download. For this either write a success block and in that block write row.reload.    cell.imageView?.imageFromServerURL("http://example.com/0x0ss2.jpg")
              row.reload()

Comment: @WilsonXJ the local is showing fine without clicking the row.

Comment: @BhupeshPruthi I think it is now working. I didn't create a success block but in the dispatch_async of the image downloader that is where I put: `myViewController.form.rowByTag("xxx")?.baseCell.imageView?.image = image`. The Image is now showing without clicking the row. Thank you!

Comment: @JaysonTamayo  i find `form[indexPath].updateCell()` at `FormViewController`'s `Datasource Method`,  it will call  `cellUpdate ` what i said above is wrong .

Comment: @BhupeshPruthi I just noticed that I am getting an infinite loop

Comment: Would you share the code, where you are updating the cell? I suggest don't extend imageView, even that might work after some tricks. Write a connection class with closure. Make sure service is on background queue and update of cell is on main queue.

Comment: @BhupeshPruthi I ended up not using an extension for UIImageView. I just used the code inside and add the row only after the image has been downloaded.

Comment: Until the image is downloading you can show activity indicator on uiimageview if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replace your code in your extension for this

```
extension UIImageView {


    public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String,closure:((loaded : Bool) -> Void)?) {

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.image = image
                if(closure != nil)
                {
                    closure!(loaded: true)
                }
            })

        }).resume()
    }

}
```

and then use this code to reload the cell

```
<<< ButtonRow("aaa") {
                $0.title = ""
                }.cellUpdate { cell, row in
                    cell.imageView?.imageFromServerURL("http://example.com/0x0ss2.jpg", closure: { (loaded) in
                        row.reload()
                    })
                }.cellSetup({ (cell, row) -> () in
                    row.cell.height = {
                        return 150
                    }
                })
```

I hope this helps, regards